Non relative GOT relocation leading to segfault
I'm fiddling around a bit with gnu asm and relocation types.
I just noticed that just using @GOT instead of @GOTPCREL(%rip) leads to a segfault for me.
I have no idea what is going wrong there.
.text
.global main

main:

sub $8, %rsp

leaq hello(%rip), %rdi
call *printf@GOT

movq $60, %rax
syscall

.data
hello:
  .string "Hello, World!\n"

Build with gcc test.S -o test
Does anyone know what is going on here?
Doing this instead:
.text
.global main

main:

sub $8, %rsp

leaq hello(%rip), %rdi
call *printf@GOTPCREL(%rip)

movq $60, %rax
syscall

.data
hello:
  .string "Hello, World!\n"

and also building with gcc test.S -o test works fine, though.

The @GOT only fills in the offset relative to the GOT, you need to add the base address yourself.

Ah, ok. That seems a bit counterintuitive for me. What is the standard way to use that relocation?

@user108813 The @GOT was designed for i386, which lacks RIP-relative addressing.  There, you first obtain the address of the GOP by some means and then use that as a base address for accessing things in the GOT using the @GOT relocation.
